# My application can't start. It crashes on open

Tags: java, android

The andriod can not start the application

tried to clean the project does not work. App Crash before opening.

```
 @Override 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    list.add("Hallo");
    list.add("Nikola");
    list.add("Lamar");

    ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myView);
    view.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to access your views after setting content view. Your views don't exist in hierarchy until that. You could try something like this:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    list.add("Hallo");
    list.add("Nikola");
    list.add("Lamar");

    ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myView);
    view.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
}
```